# Visual Studio 2015 std::map watch

Tags: c++, dictionary, visual-studio-2015, mfc, std

Using Visual Studio 2015 I have an object in a MFC extension DLL which contains a

```
class __declspec(dllexport) CGrafoPNT_2D
{
public:
    // ...
    std::map<int, CNodoGrafoPNT_2D> m_Nodi;
};

// Test Application:
class CTestApp
{
public:
    CGrafoPNT_2D m_Grafo;
};
// Test Dialog:
void CTestDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    // Debug hit condition...
}
```

when I put a breakpoint somewhere in my test application to see what's going on in m_Nodi I can't see it in my Watch as you can see in the image below.

[image: Watch object outside the object's function.]

Am I missing something in exporting the object?

**EDIT**

Following the request of a comment I add these informations:

1. The application flows regularly;
2. The application is compiled in DEBUG mode with no optimizations enabled;
3. I expect to see the content of map, which I can IF i step in any function of class CGrafoPNT_2D, as you can see in the image below.

[image: Watch object inside a function of CGrafoPNT_2D]

Comment: What did you expect to see in the window?  It is difficult to figure out exactly what you were expecting.  Second, *Am I missing something in exporting the object?* -- Does your program work?  If so, then it has nothing to do with exporting the object.  It is about how the debugger works.  Last, if you compiled with optimizations enabled, then it is highly possible to not see certain variables due to the code being optimized.

Comment: I should see the contents of map, I'll make another screenshot to see how should appear. And no: the program is compiled in debug with no optimizations, so I should see everything, moreover: if I step in any CGrafoPNT_2D function, I can see the content of map correctly.

Comment: Do you have symbol server enabled?

Comment: Where do I get this option enabled?

Comment: Don't know if this helps. But I've seen VS cranky about showing objects in my dlls. What I do is trace into any dll call and everything shows up. Hope there is an answer here as it would be nice not to have to trace in to get it to work.

Comment: @lakeweb thanks. By the way only map-like objects are affected by this bug seems, my vector are show correctly.

Comment: Yes, I see the same kind of results. One dll in particular, an XML engine. From outside I can see parts of it, but the nodes have no flyouts. Trace in and all the info shows. Other of my dlls don't seem to have this issue. It has been this way at least since vs2010 for me. I'm using 2015 now, same thing.

Comment: Bug submitted to Microsoft. By the way: I've reopened the project and now I can see the objects…

Comment: I'm seeing similar behavior with std::map in VS2019.  My map is std::map<CString, complexPtr> and I was hoping to see the key values.
I expect it's my learning curve on using Watch.